# Monomorphism and Epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Example 6.9, pg 241, Number Theory and Abstract Algebra, Cracking the GRE Math Subject Test (4th Edition):

> Let $U$ be the multiplicative group of the $n$th roots of unity; this group is cyclic of order $n$ and is generated by $w=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$. If we define $\Phi:(\Bbb Z,+)\to U$ by the equation $\Phi(a)=w^a$, show that $\Phi$ is a homomorphism. Is $\Phi$ a monomorphism? An epimorphism? An isomorphism?

**QUESTION**
I know $\Phi$ is homomorphic. I also know that $\Phi$ cannot be isomorphic because $\Bbb Z$ is infinite while $U$ is finite and an infinite group cannot be isomorphic to a finite one. However, the textbook claims $\Phi$ is not monomorphic (and I think this is correct) by using the concept of the triviality of the kernel of $\Phi$ but in this case, I do not really understand how they used that to arrive at their conclusion. We know that if $\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)$ implies $a=b$, then $\Phi$ is monomorphic. This appears to be true in this case, a contradiction to what the textbook claims (again, I do not claim to be correct). So, what I'm I missing here?

Lastly, the book claims $\Phi$ is epimorphic but does not show how or why. We know that if we can show that $\Phi(w^a)=a$, then the veracity of the claim is established. Again, I do not know how to prove this.

I will really appreciate it if someone can shed light on this for me. I will also welcome different approaches that can be used to solve these problems apart from the ones discussed above.

Comment: Remember the definition of $U$ in your approach to proving that $\Theta$ is an epimorphism. Your approach doesn't really make sense, as $w^a$ is not in general an element of $\Bbb Z,$ unless $a$ is an element of the kernel of $\Theta,$ and in any case we will never have $\Theta(w^a)=a.$

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your post to make the math expressions easier to read ( you can take a look here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference if you are interested). I guessed the $\emptyset$ symbol was supposed to be a $\Phi$, so I decided to write that; the $\Theta$ in Cameron's comment above is supposed to denote the same morphism.

Comment: Thanks @ Arnaud

Comment: @MrProf: please note that one does not usually say, like you did, in usual mathematical English "$\Phi$ is homomorphic", nor "$\Phi$ is isomorphic". There is no mathematical reason why this  is wrong (but it is), just linguistic convention.  Usual is to say "$\Phi$ is a homomorphism". The word "homomorphic" only lives in composites like "homomorphic image". For example you could say: "Every module over a commutative ring is a homomorphic image of a *free* such module."

Comment: @MrProf: please note that Cameron Blue pointed out to you that $\Phi(w^a)=a$ *does not type-check*, to use modern language. Please correct this.

Comment: @MrProf: another linguistic advice, knowing what a burden it can be to write a language which was not sung at one's cradle: while "the veracity of the claim is established" is correct modern English, it reads (to me) unnatural, verging on the parodistic. You very likely do not mean to sound like this.

Answer (score 4):

Re

> We know that if $\Phi(a)=\Phi(b)$ implies $a=b$, then $\Phi$ is monomorphic. This appears to be true in this case, a contradiction to what the textbook claims.

No, this simply is not true: $\Phi(0)=\Phi(n)$, by (what in an exp-free-context is often called) de Moivre's formula, yet $0\neq n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, hence it is indeed not a monomorphism.

EDIT: re your request for "different approaches": this problem that this textbook is posing to you is so narrow that there hardly is any leeway for "different approaches", which is why you will not get many, I think. The best I can think of is to tell you that $w = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}) = \exp(i\frac{2\pi}{n})$, where $\exp$ denotes the exponential function. It is a better "method" to treat such problems using $\exp$, already for the psychological reason that this way, you will have to work with *one* argument-parenthesis-pair instead two. (Note also the redundancy in having to write $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ **twice** when working with the raw de Moivre's formula only.) Using $\exp$ can justifiably be called a "method" for example because it allows you to use the laws for exponentiation to e.g. see why $\Phi(n)=\Phi(0)$, since $\Phi(n)=w^n=(\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{n}))^n=(\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}})^n=\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}\cdot n} = \mathrm{e}^{i\cdot2\pi}$ $=$ (periodicity of $\exp$) $=$ $\mathrm{e}^{i\cdot 0}$ $=$ $\mathrm{e}^{0}$ $=$ $1$ $=$ $\Phi(0)$. If you want, you can view what you just witnessed to be a *toy example* of a *method*, in the sense that it took me no conscious thinking to turn the crank (as they say) and grind out the preceding calculation. In principle your request for "different methods" is commendable, this problem however happens to be too easy for such a request be appropriate. I hope this helps. Best wishes.

Comment: Okay. So how can we show that every element in U has a pre image in Z

Comment: @MrProf: re your question about surjectivity($=$being an epimorphism): this is obvious from the very *definition* of $\Phi$ **if** you are allowed to use as a fact that $w$ is a generator of $U$. Are you allowed this as a hypothesis. I do not know what more there is to say about surjectivity.

Comment: Thanks for the eye opener @ Peter

Comment: In all honesty, I have learnt a lot from you today @ Peter Heinig